# Android select PDF using Intent on API 18

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I'm using following codes to select a PDF file using `Intent`. It perfectly works on Android 5.0+ but no suitable application to open a PDF file message appears on API 18.

```
public static Intent pickPdf() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    return intent;
}

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickPdf(), "Open with"), PICK_PDF);
```

Comment: There is nothing built into Android that necessarily handles that `Intent` action for that MIME type.

Comment: @CommonsWare If you want to select a PDF file using `Intent` from the storage, How would you do that?

Comment: Have a fallback of displaying your own choosing UI (use `MediaStore` to find all `application/pdf` files, show in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`).

Answer (score 2):

As @CommonsWare suggested -- there is no guarantee that an app, which handles PDFs is installed.

How I've solved this before is by using an [App Chooser](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser), like so:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
    ShowToast(TAG, "Unable to open PDF. Please, install a PDF reader app.");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to open a specific PDF file, I just need to select it from the storage and get its URI on `onActivityResult`method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to select pdf from storage and get URI

> ```
> private static final int PICK_PDF = 123;
> ```

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
> intent.setType("application/pdf");
> startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PDF);

put below code in onActivityResult

```
if (requestCode == PICK_PDF && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            //Display an error
            Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            //here is the uri you can do what you want
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error:"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     }
```